# Empezar un servicio a una hora determinada

Tags: android, android-asynctask, servicio

Estoy intentado crear un servicio que corra y ejecute unas tareas en back.
Tiene que empezar a ejecutarse a una hora y acabar a otra.
Por ejemplo un servicio que empiece a correr a las 3:00h y que pare a las 7:00h.

Estoy viendo ejemplos con la clase `Service`, pero no tengo claro como lanzarlo y pararlo a la hora que quiero.

```
public class AutoIndexadorService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new IndexerMasterViewsTask().execute();
        new IndexerWorkViewsTask().execute();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Las `AsyncTask`

> IndexerMasterViewsTask().execute();

y

> IndexerWorkViewsTask().execute()

deberán estar corriendo constantemente durante ese periodo, desde las 3:00h hasta las 7:00h

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaria usar el servicio de la alarma para poder lanzar ciertos eventos cada cierto tiempo

se llama `AlarmManager`

para poder utilizarlo es simple, esto lo puedes inizialisar en tu `onCreate()` de la primer activity por donde pasa el usuario, entonces apenas inicia la app ya se programa el servicio a ejecutarse

```
// Verificamos si la tarea ya ha sido programada. Si no, entonces crea la tarea en AlarmManager.
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
        new Intent("com.example.dummy.AlarmReceiver"), 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

if (  !alarmUp) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.dummy.AlarmReceiver");
    intent.putExtra("activate", true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
                                          intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);   
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);   
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, 
                  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2);          

}
```

Entonces, lo que estamos haciendo arriba es la consulta de un PendingIntent que coincida con nuestro nombre de clase Activity que se ejecutará a la hora programada. La bandera PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE es importante; de lo contrario, si no encuentra nuestra clase programada como PendingIntent, la creará automáticamente. Si la tarea aún no está programada, entonces avanzamos y la creamos.

Y luego necesitamos una clase que llamaremos AlarmReceiver que va a ser la que se va a ejecutar cuando llegue a ese horario determinado, recuerda que este servicio corre en background y aunque minimizes o mates la app se lanzara igual

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (!intent.hasExtra("activate")) {
            new IndexerMasterViewsTask().execute();
    new IndexerWorkViewsTask().execute();

        }

        /// your processing code comes here

    }
}
```

si encuentra el extra activate que lo pasamos cuando creamos la nueva alarma va a lanzar los dos asynctasks

recuerda que para setear la hora lo seteas aca

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);   
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Espero te sirva