# Mostrar notificación tras X minutos en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicación por la que requiero de una notificación pasados unos minutos desde que el usuario pulsa un botón y no tengo ni idea de como lograrlo.

Estuve viendo AlarmManager pero lo veo más complejo de lo que yo busco y me cuesta comprender ese código, y no sé si habrá alguna forma más sencilla. Lo que básicamente busco es:

- Pulsar un botón en la aplicación, y a las 3 horas se muestra una notificación avisando al usuario, estando la aplicación cerrada, y aunque el usuario haya apagado el teléfono, a poder ser.

Gracias de antemano,

Comment: hace 10 minutos respondi algo similar, podes verlo aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173913/empezar-un-servicio-a-una-hora-determinada/174001#174001

Comment: creo que seria mas sencillo con un countDownTimer

Comment: Agrega lo que has tratado o investigado Macia, revisar [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira creo que esta es una manera muy sencilla

Crea esta clase:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
    super(startTime, interval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    //aqui pones el codigo de la notificacion o la funcion lo que qieras
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
}
```

}

Para inicializarlo creas una variable

```
CountDownTimer bla = new MyCountDownTimer(tiempoQueQuieresQueDure, intervalo);
```

El intervalo debe ser 1000 pues es en milisegundos y lo que qieres es que cada 3 horas esto suceda pues lo llamarias asi

```
int time=180*60*1000, intervalo=1000;
CountDownTimer bla = new MyCountDownTimer(time, intervalo);
```

Y el metodo onFinish sucede cuando llegue a 0. Para iniciarlo solo llama al metodo nombreCDT.start();

Espero que esto te ayude cualquier duda pregunta

Comment: Pero de esta manera, al reiniciar el dispositivo no funcionaría verdad? Además, no consumirá demasiados recursos del smartphone?

Comment: si reinicias no, esto solo funciona con la aplicacion en background o en primer plano. como pediste algo sencillo esto fue lo que te puse que crei que te pudiera ayudar

Comment: Si no consigo hacerlo con el AlarmManger lo haré de esta forma en el peor de los casos. Gracias.